Load global dll in WPF C# application as a link without it having to be copied into output directory
I have the following problem:
I am working on multiple WPF applications, which all have to use the same dll.
This dll lies in a directory of my choice but I want dont want to copy it to all the single application output directories, so I can make changes on the dll without having to recompile all the applications that use that dll.
How can I link the dll to an application in Visual Studio 2022 as reference or whatever, without the dll having to be copied in the output directory of the application on the build process?
I have already tried to add the dll as an existing element but I could not get the project to find the dll like that. When I add them as a reference they either have to be copied to the output directory or the dll would not be recognised.
one extra: i've got another dll with some custom usercontrols I want to use (I created the project as a usercontrol library if that helps). The best option would be to somehow link this other dll in a way so I can use the usercontrols directly in the XAML window, so I cant really load the dll at runtime. How would I do that?
Thanks for any help in advance,
David
EDIT: I am using .NET Framework 4.8.1

Normally, you would just add an assembly reference to that DLL in each of your (application-) projects. It should get copied automatically to any output folders for projects that require it. Any reason why you specifically don't want to have that DLL in the output folders? For the second question it would similarily be easiest to add the usercontrol project to your solution and add a project reference to all projects that need it.

The reason I dont want the dll in the output folder is: if I want to make an update for the dll i dont want to recompile/rebuild all the projects that use the dll but I want the projects to use the updated dll. So I want to link the project to the dll or the path to the dll but not have it be inside of the projects output folder. And the same thing would apply for the second question aswell

What about using code like this Assembly.LoadFile("path/to/your/library.dll");?

If you can replace the DLL in the central location, you can likewise replace it in all the application folders; no need to recompile. So I don't get your motivation.

Another idea is to create a post-build step in all your projects to create a symbolic link in the output dir pointing to your one dll, instead of copying it. This will allow you to simply update the dll in one location.

Thanks for the help. In the end I figured it out myself yesterday with a little help of Copilot. Copilot suggested something similar to @Oleg Nesterov 's answer.
I added the dll as a normal reference but set local copy to false, so the dll wont be copied to the output folder. Then I wrote the following code into my startup class:
private List<string> dllsToLoad = new List<string> {
    "dllToLoad.dll"
};

public App() {
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += OnResolveAssembly;
}

private Assembly OnResolveAssembly(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args) {
    string assemblyName = new AssemblyName(args.Name).Name + ".dll";
    // check if the dll needs to be loaded
    if (dllsToLoad.Contains(assemblyName)) {
        string assemblyPath = Path.Combine(@"path/to/dll", assemblyName);
        if (File.Exists(assemblyPath)) {
            return Assembly.LoadFrom(assemblyPath);
        } else {
            MessageBox.Show($"Could not find the dll {assemblyPath}.");
            Application.Current.Shutdown();
        }
    }
    return null;
}

I will also try to solve it by using the symbolic link @NPras mentioned. Another thing I will look into is the reference path folders you can add in the properties of the project, but I didnt get that to work for now.
